# Why signal add noise cause signal undiscoverable after `fft` and `ifft`？

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, ifft, time-frequency

As we all know, Fourier transform of the sinc(t) is rect(f).
Simple python script to discover signal after `fft` and `ifft` with random normal noise.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)

peak=np.fft.fft(np.sinc(np.linspace(-4, 4, 200)))
peak_ifft=np.fft.ifft(peak)
n=200
noise=np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=np.sqrt(2)/2, size=(n, 2)).view(np.complex128)
signal=noise+np.reshape(np.asarray(peak),(-1,1))
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(np.abs(signal))
plt.title('power vs freq')
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
signal_ifft=np.fft.ifft(signal)
plt.plot(signal_ifft)
plt.title('should appear sinc,but not')
plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.plot(peak_ifft)
plt.title('should be sinc,and yes')
plt.show()
```

Output as below:
[image]

As `x(t)+y(t)<->X(f)+Y(f)`,`np.fft.ifft(np.fft(signal))`  go back to origin `signal`,why cannot `np.fft.ifft(np.fft(signal+noise))`?

Comment: you don't add, you *concatenate*, completely different operations.

Comment: Can you please **confirm** that you want to use `np.concatenate`, and that you have indeed read and understood it's documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to just do signal + noise, and you'll be fine for the noise part.

For the plot, you need the absolute of the fft, you're just plotting the real part.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)
# make data
x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 200)
y = np.sinc(x)
# make fft and ifft
peak = np.fft.fft(y)
peak_ifft = np.fft.ifft(peak)
# make the frequency domain
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(x), np.diff(x).mean())
# make some noise!!!
n = 200
noise = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.1, size=n)
# signal with noise, and the fft and ifft
signal = y + noise
peak2 = np.fft.fft(signal)
peak_ifft2 = np.fft.ifft(peak2)
# plotting
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, peak_ifft, ':')
plt.figure()
plt.plot(freq, np.abs(peak))
plt.xlim([-5,5])
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, signal)
plt.plot(x, peak_ifft2, ':')
plt.figure()
plt.plot(freq, np.abs(peak2))
plt.xlim([-5.,5])
```

[image]

Comment: when you use `add`,get the similar output

Comment: I've refined my answer to be more explanatory and to have a full example. Does that help?

Comment: Really thanks for your clear answer.